# Republish Docker Image with Preserved Digest to Different Registry

Tags: docker, hash, preserve, skopeo

I pull images from public registries such as DockerHub, and push them to a singular private registry. This is a simple process for images in the format of `image:tag` but not so for those of `image@digest`.

I want to re-publish, or push in Docker's terminology, images from a public registry to my private registry whilst maintaining the integrity of the exact immutable image. I want to preserve the digest so there's no abstraction between the digest referenced from my private registry to the image's source in a public registry.

I attempted to perform the same `docker push` command that works for `image:tag` on `image@digest`, but to no avail.

**image:tag push**

```
docker login -u usr -p psw registry.io
docker image pull docker.io/alpine:3.17.0
docker image push registry.io/alpine:3.17.0
...
ok
```

**image@digest: push**

```
docker login -u usr -p psw registry.io
docker image pull docker.io/alpine@sha256:c0d488a800e4127c334ad20d61d7bc21b4097540327217dfab52262adc02380c
docker image push registry.io/alpine@sha256:c0d488a800e4127c334ad20d61d7bc21b4097540327217dfab52262adc02380c
...
cannot push a digest reference
```

I want to re-publish the image from source to target as-is. I could perform a re-tag, or a push with a different ID, but both result in altering the reference-able digest and a level of abstraction that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72549515/596285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this using Docker. Instead, I investigated Skopeo. [v1.6.0](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/releases/tag/v1.6.0) introduced the `--preserve-digests` flag that sounded laughably perfect. It was.

I implemented it as follows:

```
skopeo copy \
    --dest-creds='usr:psw' \
    --preserve-digests \
    --override-arch amd64 \
    docker://docker.io/alpine@sha256:c0d488a800e4127c334ad20d61d7bc21b4097540327217dfab52262adc02380c \
    docker://registry.io/alpine@sha256:c0d488a800e4127c334ad20d61d7bc21b4097540327217dfab52262adc02380c
```

After I'd completed the digest-preserving copy, I had some additional bits that I wanted to add but found the documentation a bit hard to navigate. I eventually found all of the answers and supplemental flags that I was looking for, so thought I should post here in case they help someone else. I had to read through the available [transports](https://github.com/containers/skopeo#skopeo) (repository types) for use in Skopeo's [copy](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/main/docs/skopeo-copy.1.md#options) command, which is where I discovered `--dest-creds` and `--preserve-digests`, and I wasn't able to discover `--override-arch` as a [global flag](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/1add7a81d769e734d7419e7e9f3f38d1ac746987/docs/skopeo.1.md#options) immediately!

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tools for managing images on registries. And most support copying the image, including the multi-platform manifest, without modifying the digest. A few examples include:

- google/go-containerregistry's crane (`crane copy`)
- RedHat's skopeo (`skopeo copy`)
- My own regclient's regctl (`regctl image copy`)

Using the docker CLI won't work for this because pulling an image to docker dereferences the multi-platform manifest to your platform's image. And when docker pushes an image, it may regenerate the image manifest json, possibly losing data like annotations, or changing spacing, and any single character change in the marshaled json will change the digest.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is **rename** the image and then push it. When you push an image to a repository you are pushing it to the repository specified by the image name. So first rename (changing the `tag` really) to include the registry you want to push to, then do the push.

```
docker image pull centos:centos7
docker tag centos:centos7 my-registry.io/centos7:centos7
docker push my-registry.io/centos/centos7
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but unfortunately my question refers to republishing an image@digest - not an image:tag. I'm thinking Skopeo might be the answer.

Comment: If a label is an alias for a digest, will pushing an image based on a label fulfill your requirement?

Comment: That depends on whether I'd be able to pull the image exactly as normal i.e. `docker pull my-registry.io/centos/centos7@sha256:8faead07bd1d5fdd17414a1759eae004da5daa9575a846f4730f44dec0f47843`